# Problem decoding json strings using json module

Tags: python, json, reddit

After contacting a server I get the following strings as response

```
{"kind": "t2", "data": {"has_mail": null, "name": "shadyabhi", "created": 1273919273.0, "created_utc": 1273919273.0, "link_karma": 1343, "comment_karma": 301, "is_gold": false, "is_mod": false, "id": "425zf", "has_mod_mail": null}}
```

which is stored as **type 'str'** in my script.

Now, when I try to decode it using json.dumps(mystring, sort_keys=True, indent=4), I get this.

```
"{\"kind\": \"t2\", \"data\": {\"has_mail\": null, \"name\": \"shadyabhi\", \"created\": 1273919273.0, \"created_utc\": 1273919273.0, \"link_karma\": 1343, \"comment_karma\": 301, \"is_gold\": false, \"is_mod\": false, \"id\": \"425zf\", \"has_mod_mail\": null}}"
```

which should really be like this

```
shadyabhi@archlinux ~ $ echo '{"kind": "t2", "data": {"has_mail": "null", "name": "shadyabhi", "created": 1273919273.0, "created_utc": 1273919273.0, "link_karma": 1343, "comment_karma": 299, "is_gold": "false", "is_mod": "false", "id": "425zf", "has_mod_mail": "null"}}' | python2 -mjson.tool
{
    "data": {
        "comment_karma": 299, 
        "created": 1273919273.0, 
        "created_utc": 1273919273.0, 
        "has_mail": "null", 
        "has_mod_mail": "null", 
        "id": "425zf", 
        "is_gold": "false", 
        "is_mod": "false", 
        "link_karma": 1343, 
        "name": "shadyabhi"
    }, 
    "kind": "t2"
}
shadyabhi@archlinux ~ $
```

So, what is it that's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load it before you can dump it.  Try this:

```
data = json.loads(returnFromWebService)

json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

To add a bit more detail - you're receiving a string, and then asking the json library to dump it to a string.  That doesn't make a great deal of sense.  What you need to do first is put the data into a more meaningful container.  By calling `loads` you take the string value of the return and parse it into an actual Python Dictionary.  Then, you can pass that data to `dumps` which outputs a string using your requested formatting.

Comment: Aha, while looking at the documentation, I was wondering as to how to get that obj. Now, I know. So, by using loads, I deserialize the string.

Answer (score 1):

You have things backwards. If you want to convert a string to a data structure you need to use `json.loads(thestring)`. `json.dumps()` is for converting a data structure to a json encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to `dump` an object (like a dictionary) which then becomes a string, not the other way round... see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Use `json.loads()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want `json.loads`.  The `dumps` method is for going the other way (dumping an object to a json string).